# Kotlin String to Int value is wrong

Tags: kotlin

This is my code:

```
fun main(){
  val str = "123"
  println(str.toInt()) // 123
  println(str[1].toInt()) // 50 ???
}
```

I want number 2.
But it's result number 50.

I didn't want ASCII code number.

How can I get a solution?

Comment: Try printing `str[1]`. What does that say?

Comment: try using substr()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the second character in the `String`, you can do

```
println(str[1])
```

And if you want to convert the second character to an `Int`, then you should do

```
println(str[1].toString().toInt())
```

Please note that `toInt`() can throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: I thought str [n] returned a string.
Now I know that str [n] returns a character.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII value of character '2' is 50 (decimal).
Looks like you want a substring operation to get the string "2" (or "23" ?)  rather than character indexing that gets the char '2'.